# How to create a multiple stacked bar chart with MPAndroidChart?

Tags: android, mpandroidchart

Here's the json, and I would like to display the graph shown with the [MPAndroidChart library](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart) [image].

```
[
    {
        "MonthName": "February",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 3,
        "ClientName": "A",
        "IssueStatus": "Total",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "February",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 13,
        "ClientName": "B",
        "IssueStatus": "Total",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "February",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 1,
        "ClientName": "A",
        "IssueStatus": "Closed",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "February",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 2,
        "ClientName": "B",
        "IssueStatus": "Closed",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "February",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 1,
        "ClientName": "A",
        "IssueStatus": "OutStanding",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "February",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 10,
        "ClientName": "B",
        "IssueStatus": "OutStanding",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "March",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 1,
        "ClientName": "A",
        "IssueStatus": "OutStanding",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "March",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 0,
        "ClientName": "B",
        "IssueStatus": "OutStanding",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "March",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 0,
        "ClientName": "A",
        "IssueStatus": "Closed",

    {
        "MonthName": "March",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 0,
        "ClientName": "B",
        "IssueStatus": "Closed",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "March",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 3,
        "ClientName": "A",
        "IssueStatus": "Total",

    },
    {
        "MonthName": "March",
        "Year": "2016",
        "IssuesCount": 9,
        "ClientName": "B",
        "IssueStatus": "Total",

    }
]
```

I'm using MPAndroidChart library, please suggest how to proceed with this. I'm facing difficulty in grouping the details for particular month and showing multiple bars for single month.

**EDIT**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is possible.

What you need:

- 1 `BarData` object, filled with:
- 3 datasets (one for the red bars, one for the purple, ...)
- and each dataset is filled with stacked `BarEntries`
- the space between the "bar-groups" can be set via `barData.setGroupSpace(...)`
- the space between the individual bars can be set via `barDataSet.setBarSpace(...)`

A stacked `BarEntry` can be created like this:

```
new BarEntry(new float[] { stackvalue1, stackvalue2 }, xIndex);
```

The `xIndex` corresponds to the month on the x-axis the entry should map to (in your case).

[This example](https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart/blob/master/MPChartExample/src/com/xxmassdeveloper/mpchartexample/BarChartActivityMultiDataset.java) creates a chart just like the one you are showing in the image above.

Comment: As you can see in the image, is there any way we can add white space (gap) in between the stacks ?

Comment: I'm not sure if you understood my question. Please check the edited question.

Comment: Ah, okay. Yes simply add a value between the actual stacks and assign color transparent.